# PySpark - Duplicate rows N times with ID column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, duplicates

Suppose I have a PySpark dataframe with x rows. I want to create a dataframe with x * n rows, with each row in the original dataframe duplicated n times, along with an additional column giving an ID for each duplicate. The ID should just be 0 to n-1.

There will be no duplicate rows in the resulting dataframe, as the ID is unique for each duplicate. However considering the dataframe without the ID column, there will be n duplicates of each row.

How can I achieve this efficiently in PySpark?

Thanks

Comment: you could create a dummy array with the IDs and explode it. something similar was asked a few days back -- [see](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76557596/8279585).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `explode` function on an array generated from the `range(n)` python function:

```py
from pyspark.sql import function as F
n = 3
df = spark.range(2)
df.withColumn("new_index", F.explode(
    F.array(
        [F.lit(i) for i in range(n)]
    )
)).show()
```

```
+---+---------+
| id|new_index|
+---+---------+
|  0|        0|
|  0|        1|
|  0|        2|
|  1|        0|
|  1|        1|
|  1|        2|
+---+---------+
```